# Keep Meteor Template Rendered After Routing

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I want to allow my meteor app to work if a user goes offline. As of right now I am using Iron-router as my router. My App works great until a user goes off line and tries to navigate around the app. The current page is fine but the routes are blank. Is there a way render all of my routes on app start-up and continue to hold all of the template info even if the application was to go offline. I know I can achieve this with the use of a native app i.e using cordova. However is there a convenient way to do this without creating a native application?

Comment: You could try calling [Meteor.disconnect()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_disconnect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an app to be available for the client even though it's not connected to the Internet you could try [AppCache](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/appcache). It puts content in the browsers Application Cache, which will be used it there's no connection to the server. Then your routes will work even if there's no connectivity.

```
meteor add appcache
```

Together with [GroundDb](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db) (for offline collections) you can make your application very functional even if you're offline.

```
meteor add ground:db
```